# Why is a string literal considered as an lvalue expression when it cannot be referenced?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I am trying to understand lvalue expressions.

In the following link [cppreference-value-categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) I read the following statement under the 'lvalue' section.

> The following expressions are lvalue expressions:
>
> a string literal, such as "Hello, world!";

Could someone explain why this is an lvalue rather than a rvalue?

Comment: String literals are really constant arrays of characters, and can therefore be used much like other (constant) arrays in your program (including getting their address taken with the address-of operator `&`).